# Regex to find a quote within paired double quotes

Tags: regex, double-quotes

Please help me with a regex that is enclosed within a pair of double quotes.

Here is the example:

> Matching a ' within "double ***'*** quotes" is what i am ' looking for
>   "in this ***'*** question"  can ' anybody help

As marked, I need the bold ' to be picked up

Quotes within

- "double ***'*** quotes
- "in this ***'*** question"

are the only ones the regex should identify.

Comment: Please reformat your question.

Comment: What language are you doing this in?

Comment: through negative lookahead `'(?!(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)`

Answer (score 0):

```
'(?=[^"]*"(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/5